# Efficient way to handle Firebase Authentication error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, error-handling, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm currently using Firebase Authentication in JavaScript and trying to create a function to register users. The first step I need to check is the availability of e-mail usage. Whether it's used or not using `getUserByEmail()` function. If the email hasn't been used, continue the register step, otherwise, return an object containing error status and error message.

The thing is, `getUserByEmail()` function is returning a Promise. So if the provided email hasn't registered, the function will return an error. This is understandable because the function is Promise-based. But what bothers me is the syntax order because it is "reversed" since from what I usually do is the `try` block is to execute "right steps" and the `catch` block is to execute the "wrong steps". Here's the code I wrote:

```js
try {
    const findFirebaseUser = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email);

    return {
        status: false,
        message: 'Email has been used'
    }
} catch (error) {
    if (error.errorInfo.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
        // register step
        const { uid } = await admin.auth().createUser({
            displayName: name,
            password,
            email,
            phoneNumber
        });
      
        await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, { role });

        return {
            status: true,
            message: 'Success'
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way I could do to write the steps more efficient? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the above style bothers you, just refactor the code to look like this:

```
const exists = await isUserExists(email);
if (exists) {
  return { status: false, message: 'already exists' };
}
// Create and set claims



async function isUserExists(email) {
  try {
    await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email);
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought to put the positive case in the try block and handle the error based on the error message in the catch block. But this is neater. Thanks!